# Python sub-process changes the timestamp of a file it should not touch

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess, spyder, netcdf

#### Situation

I am working with Python from the IDE Spyder 2.2.5 in a Linux OS (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

I am editing and creating netcdf files using the utilities `ncdump` (conversion from binary nc to source cdl format) and `ncgen` (viceversa).

The command `ncgen file.cdl` merely checks the syntax of the source code. If you want to create an entirely new binary file, you have to launch `ncgen -b file.cdl` instead. (Source `man ncgen`.)

#### Evidence

**From the Linux terminal --** If I run `ncgen file.cdl` from the command line, the time stamp of the extant `file.nc` does not change (as seen with `ls -lht file.nc`).
This is normal because a syntax control on the cdl source does not create any new binary file.

**From the Python IDE --** If I give the same instructions from a Python script using the module subprocess (`import subprocess as sp`)

```
sp.check_call(["ncgen", "file.cdl"])  # ncgen file.cdl
sp.check_call(["ls", "-lth", "file.nc"])  # ls -lth file.nc
```

then the time stamp of the file.nc is updated to the time of running this.
It does not matter whether I invoke `ncgen` with the method `sp.check_call()` or `sp.call()`.
Also, the Linux terminal shows this new time stamp too, so the change is not a fiction of the Python console.

The Python script does create a fresh `file.cdl`.
However, the sub-process invocation changes the time stamp of another file `file.nc` that, in principle, had not to be touched.

Interestingly, other files unrelated to this netcdf job live in the same directory.
These are not touched.
So the combination of the module subprocess and the command `ncgen` may be a factor in this situation.

#### Issue

I'd expect that running `ncgen file.cdl` does not touch the time stamp of `file.nc` as it happens when operating from the Linux terminal.

The handling of the time stamp in the Python environment is confusing. I cannot tell how old the output netcdf file that I have is, and act accordingly.

- Is this behaviour expected (XFAIL situation)? How can I then control this?
- What could be the reasons for this to occur unexpectedly (FAIL situation)?

Comment: Use strace to find out if and how your file(s) are touched.

Comment: @scai Would you please elaborate on how to implement your suggestion in a way that it addresses the post questions? There is already evidence that the files are touched (time-stamp change) while they should not, in my view.

Comment: I could not reproduce this on macOS 10, Ubuntu 12 or Ubuntu 16. Not sure what you mean by python IDE. I just ran command line py scripts.

Comment: @EricBridger OS should not matter since it goes according to expectations there: mine is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS anyhow. The Python IDE in point is Spyder 2.2.5 -- my script is written and executed in there. Post edited.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this behavior on Mint18....

Comment: From the command line your 2 line script does not produce the results you claim. My guess is this is a Spyder IDE issue so I'd add the spyder tag to your question.

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) Spyder 2.2 is four years old. Please update to Spyder 3.1.4 (our latest version) and try again.